# Implementing Pre-Conditioned Conjugate Gradient with PETSc

Tags: c, matlab, gradient-descent, petsc

I'm writing some C code to run OLS on a large dataset of approximately 40 million observations. I am interested in using pre-conditioned conjugate gradient algorithm (PCG) utilizing incomplete Cholesky (ICC) decomposition to obtain the preconditioner. I have a MATLAB code that does the same correctly and that is to be used as a benchmark to make sure that the C script is correct. In short, I want to replicate MATLAB's "ichol" and "pcg" procedures using C.

Currently I'm using the PETSc C library for PCG and ICC. I use R to read-in the dataset and compute X'X and X'Y and I output both to text files for use by C. The matrix is in coordinate sparse format (3 vectors - one with row indices, one with column indices, and one with the value for all non-zero matrix entries). The full matrix is of size approximately 8 million by 8 million with about 166 million non-zero entries.

I read-in the files in C, construct the matrix and vector and run PCG using PETSc's procedure KSPSolve, outputting the vector of linear coefficients b to a text file. The code completes without a hitch, but the solutions I'm getting are nonsensical - coefficients on the order of 2 million, when I should be getting something like 2 or 3 (from running the MATLAB code).

However, when I restrict the dataset to a smaller subsample (e.g., the first 300,000 observations), the results from the C code and the MATLAB code align very well. After some trial and error I established that results align until I hit a very specific sample size (363,855) at which point the C code results start diverging. The divergence is not suddenly explosive - at first the maximum absolute difference between the C code and the MATLAB code is on the order of 700, but it quickly grows to the 2 million mentioned above. I looked at PETSc's internal convergence monitoring statistics and the program itself seems to think that the norm of the true residual (X'Y-X'Xb) goes down to fairly low levels (order of 10^(-3)), while if I compute the residual manually in MATLAB using the output from C, I get, unsurprisingly, very large numbers. What is more, if I take a subsample from the last (instead of the first) 363,855 or even 1 million observations, then the C code and the MATLAB code still align fairly well.

I'm looking for suggestions as to what might be going wrong here and what steps to take to diagnose/fix it. I'm fairly new to C, so basic mistakes are definitely a possibility.

The relevant section of the code is pasted below:

```
/* Read in matrix, rhs, and IA, JA, RA vectors from ascii files */

   ierr   = PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_SELF,"\n Read matrix in ascii format ...\n");CHKERRQ(ierr);
   ierr   = PetscFOpen(PETSC_COMM_SELF,Ain,"r",&Afile);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   nsizes = 3;
   fscanf(Afile,"%d,%d,%d\n",&m,&n,&nz);
   ierr = PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_SELF,"m: %d, n: %d, nz: %d \n", m,n,nz);CHKERRQ(ierr);

/*Allocating matrix and vectors*/

   ierr = MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_SELF,&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   ierr = MatSetSizes(A,PETSC_DECIDE,PETSC_DECIDE,m,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   ierr = MatSetFromOptions(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   ierr = MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation(A,nz/m,nnz_array);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   ierr = MatSetOption(A,MAT_NEW_NONZERO_ALLOCATION_ERR,PETSC_FALSE);CHKERRQ(ierr);


/*Building matrix*/

    for (i=0; i<nz; i++) {
      fscanf(Afile,"%g,%g,%le\n",&_row,&_col,(double*)&val);
      row = (PetscInt)_row;
      col = (PetscInt)_col;
      ierr = MatSetValues(A,1,&row,1,&col,&val,INSERT_VALUES);
      CHKERRQ(ierr);

    }

    ierr = MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(Afile);
    free(nnz_array);

  /*Reading-in X'Y vector*/
  ierr = VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_SELF,&b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetSizes(b,PETSC_DECIDE,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetFromOptions(b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_SELF,"\n Read rhs in ascii format ...\n");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFOpen(PETSC_COMM_SELF,rhs,"r",&bfile);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      fscanf(bfile,"%d,%le\n",&dummy,(double*)&val);
      ierr = VecSetValues(b,1,&i,&val,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    }
    ierr = VecAssemblyBegin(b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecAssemblyEnd(b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(bfile);

  /*Creating vector to store solution in*/
  ierr = VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectSetName((PetscObject) x, "Solution");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetSizes(x,PETSC_DECIDE,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetFromOptions(x);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                Create the linear solver and set various options
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  /*
     Create linear solver context
  */
  ierr = KSPCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&ksp);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Set operators. Here the matrix that defines the linear system
     also serves as the preconditioning matrix.
  */
  ierr = KSPSetOperators(ksp,A,A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Set linear solver defaults for this problem.
  */
  ierr = KSPGetPC(ksp,&pc);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PCSetType(pc,PCICC);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = KSPSetTolerances(ksp,1.e-10,1.e-10,PETSC_DEFAULT,1000);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = KSPSetType(ksp,KSPCG);
  /*
    Set runtime options.
  */
  ierr = KSPSetFromOptions(ksp);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                      Solve the linear system
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  /*
     Solve linear system
  */
    printf("\nBeginning to solve system:\n"); 
    ierr = KSPSolve(ksp,b,x);CHKERRQ(ierr);


  /*
     View solver info.
  */
  ierr = KSPView(ksp,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);CHKERRQ(ierr);
```

Comment: It sounds that you are asking to debug a large, non-trivial code for you. I don't think anyone here is going to do it.

Comment: ...as well as taking on board the context. Can you whittle the code down to find where the problem actually is?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Reading `col` and `row` using `%g` specifiers is not very usual.  If these numbers are written/read as floats, the precision is about 1e-6, thus triggering potential wrong col or wrong rows for large matrices. How about using `%d` specifiers to write and read integers?